# WPF textbox resizable text

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I am trying to create resizable textboxes (so when the window is resized the textbox adjusts itself) programatically but the text inside the textbox is always very small in comparison to the textbox:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.Name = name;
textBox.Text = text;
textBox.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, column);
textBox.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, row);
textBox.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, columnspan);
textBox.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, rowspan);
```

So i added a binding to keep the text at the same size as the textbox:

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self);
b.Path = new PropertyPath(TextBox.ActualHeightProperty);
textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.FontSizeProperty, b);
```

but when i do this the text becomes way too big for the textbox.

What am i doing wrong/missing here?

Comment: "the textbox becomes way too big for the textbox." Did you mean the text becomes way too big for the textbox?

Comment: yes thats what i meant, i have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the fontsize which is pixels to actual height which is in device independent units so its apples to oranges.

Is there any reason to not use a viewbox?

Something like (I'm doing this freehand so beware..no ide may have typos)

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
Viewbox vb = new Viewbox();

vb.Child = textbox;
vb.Stretch = Uniform;
textBox.Name = name;
textBox.Text = text;
vb.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, column);
vb.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, row);
vb.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, columnspan);
vb.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, rowspan);
```

Comment: Using viewbox does the trick for the text inside the textbox but then textbox width is shrunk to its minimum size possible until there is some text written.

Comment: Add MinWidth="50" to the TextBox maybe.

Comment: are you setting everything to horizontalalignment = stretch?

Comment: @Charlie i tried that right now and it had no effect